# Custom Scaffold class not draw the AppBar

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, appbar, scaffold

I'm trying to create a custom Scaffold extending the original class.
With a default AppBar if not passed a new one.

```
class CommonScaffold extends Scaffold {
  final AppBar? appBar;
  final Widget body;

  CommonScaffold({
    Key? key,
    this.appBar,
    required this.body,
  }) : super(
    key: key,
    body: body,
    appBar: appBar ??
        AppBar(
          title: const Text("Default Text"),
        ),
  );
}
```

If I call the class avoiding pass the appBar parameter the AppBar will not appear. But should appear.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CommonScaffold(
      body: _createContent(),
    );
  }
```

If I call the class passing an AppBar to the appBar parameter the AppBar will appear.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CommonScaffold(
      body: _createContent(),
      appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("TEST"),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is here we are having two `appBar` and `body` for `CommonScaffold`. First set is coming because of `extends Scaffold` and second set is by declaring two on `CommonScaffold`.

You can check how it works on OOP by running this snippet.
[On dartPad](https://dartpad.dev/64cc31643365c9d021a494755ac6f5fb). I'm changing names for better understanding the concept.

```dart
class Super {
  final int? a;
  final int? b;

  const Super({this.a, this.b});
}

class Common extends Super {
  final int? ca;
  final int b;

  const Common({this.ca, required this.b}) : super(a: ca ?? 10, b: b);
}

void main() {
  final c = Common(b: 1);
  print("supper a: ${c.a}"); // 10:  will refer supper class 
  print("Common a: ${c.ca}"); // null:  will refer common class 
}
```

Now for your answer, It will be better to change attributes name of `CommonScaffold` to avoid conflicting with super class.

Here is the answer on [dartPad](https://dartpad.dev/9a0f0088d4b3cb524028a5531fc636a9)

```dart
class CommonScaffold extends Scaffold {
  final AppBar? cAppBar;

  final Widget? cBody;

  CommonScaffold({
    Key? key,
    this.cAppBar,
    this.cBody,
  }) : super(
            key: key,
            body: cBody,
            appBar: cAppBar ??
                AppBar(
                  title: Text("Default Appbar"),
                ));
}

class A extends StatelessWidget {
  const A({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CommonScaffold(
      cBody: Text("body"),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you only want to show or not the appBar you can use this example by modifying the value of the bool to show or not the bar

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: (showAppbar)? AppBar(
          title: const Text("Default Text"),
        ): AppBar(
          title: const Text("TEST"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text(
          'Hello, a!',
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```